# Trying to combine Power BI tables in order to get full client list and revenue

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

One of the tables in my Power BI report is from a large database (over 7 million rows), and it contains currently active clients, along with their products and the revenue they bring by month/year/quarter. For this report, I'm trying to look at a subset of those clients (called core clients). The issue I'm having with this table, however, is that once our clients convert away from our core products, they are no longer listed as core clients. This makes it so that we can't report accurately on historic data regarding the number of core clients and the revenue associated with them.

To work around this, I have a list of all core clients going back to 2020, along with when they deconverted and what product they were using. My goal is to supplement the dataset with this client list. For current clients, I'll use the dataset. But when we go back historically, I want to go by the list of clients rather than the core tag we're using now.

I tried merging the two tables together in Power BI using Power Query, but due to the fact that there were duplicate values in both tables, the merge messed up. I then created a summarized table of the dataset, grouping by client, quarter, and revenue.

Here's the DAX formula I used for that table.

```
Customer Revenue Summary = SUMMARIZE('CustRev Revenue_Summary', 'CustRev Revenue_Summary'[UPE_ID], 'CustRev Revenue_Summary'[UPE_Name], 'CustRev Revenue_Summary'[Entity_ID], 'Customer Entity'[Entity_Name], 'CustRev Revenue_Summary'[Period_Year], 'CustRev Revenue_Summary'[Period_Quarter], 'CustRev Revenue_Summary'[Quarter - Year], "Revenue Sum", SUM('CustRev Revenue_Summary'[Revenue_USD]))
```

I'm currently trying to use CONCATENATEX to pull the values that match from both tables.I pulled in product, loss date, and the loss reason using this method.

```
LBucket_Excel = CONCATENATEX(FILTER(ALL('RCB Core Combined'), 'Customer Revenue Summary'[Entity-Quarter] = 'RCB Core Combined'[EID-Quarter]), 'RCB Core Combined'[L Bucket], ",")
```

Am I on the right track here or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm looking for? Any guidance would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the current client table and the historical table have very similar columns, then you could append these tables. They appear to be fact based tables with sales data. I would also recommend building a client dimension with active and inactive clients. You could determine if a client was active by searching against the unique list of active clients. If it's not in there, it would be inactive. More on facts and dimnesions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036905/difference-between-fact-table-and-dimension-table)